# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar un elemento de mi Spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy tratando de actualizar un formulario en Android, para ello debo seleccionar el valor exacto de la lista de objetos que fue previamente cargada al spinner, ej;

Cargué mi spinner de la siguiente manera:

```
public void cargarAdapterSentidos(ArrayList<Sentido> sentidos){
    ArrayAdapter<Sentido> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Sentido>(this,
            R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sentidos);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Pero no se cómo puede recorrer ese spinner para saber la posición de un objeto, he intentado con un cast pero no me ha funcionado:

```
Sentido s = new Sentido(9, "SANTA MARTA - CARTAGENA");
int posicion = getPosicionSpinner(s.getNombre());

public int getPosicionSpinner(String cadena){
    ArrayList<Sentido> sentidosSpinner = (ArrayList<Sentido>) spinner.getAdapter();
    for(int i = 0; i< sentidosSpinner.size(); i++){
        if(sentidosSpinner.get(i).getNombre().equals(cadena)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Lo que intento es saber la posición en la que está el objeto dentro del spinner

Answer (score 0):

Al seleccionar un elemento puedes obtener su posición de esta forma mediante el método [**getSelectedItemPosition()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition()) :

```
int posicion = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

> [**getSelectedItemPosition()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition())  Devuelve la posición del elemento
>   actualmente seleccionado dentro del conjunto de datos del adaptador

la posición obtenida inicia desde 0 (primer elemento) hasta el número de elementos en tu  spinner.

---

Si deseas seleccionar un elemento de tu Spinner puedes usar el método [**setSelection()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setSelection(int)) definiendo la posición:

```
int position = 2; //tercera posición.
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para es puede hacer uso del metodo

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String nombre = sentidos.get(position).getNombre()
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

este se ejecuta al momento de dar click sobre un item del spinner y recibes una posicion, con esa pocicion lo buscas en tu lista de objetos

Comment: eso ya lo sé, creo que no me entendieron lo que quise explicar, lo que quiero saber es la posición, es para llenar un formulario para editar información, hago la consulta en la base de datos y quiero saber en qué posición del spinner está el dato que traigo de la base de datos, para ello debo recorrer la colección del spinner para saber en qué posición se encuentra y ahí si, seleccionarlo.